# Having problems trying to resize gridworld grid

Tags: java, super, gridworld

I want to resize the grid in gridworld from the default 10x10 to whatever I want. I've been testing it with 15x15 just to see if it works. But I can't seem to figure this out and other sources on the internet say that what I'm doing should work.

The grid stays at 10x10 even though I try and set `rowSize` & `colSize`, how can I fix this so that it opens the grid to a 15x15 screen?

This class is where I resize the grid

```
import info.gridworld.actor.*;
import info.gridworld.grid.BoundedGrid;

public class pokeGrid extends ActorWorld{

    private static final int rowSize = 15;
    private static final int colSize = 15;

    public pokeGrid(){
        super(new BoundedGrid<Actor>(rowSize, colSize));
    }
}
```

This class is the runner for the actor

```
public class BeecherBugRunner extends pokeGrid {

    private static pokeGrid world = new pokeGrid();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
        BeecherBug beecher = new BeecherBug(4);
        world.add(new Location(7, 8), beecher);
        world.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders, you should update your copy-and-paste links to go to MSE instead of MSO.

Comment: @gunr2171: fixed. Good catch.

Comment: I notice that you didn't say what the posted code does. Just that "it doesn't work". In what way does it not work? Grid stays at 10x10?

Comment: Very good. Now, you're basically saying, "I made the change to 15x15, then I _tested in some way_ and the grid was still at 10x10". Please say how you tested - that is, what makes you think the grid is still 10x10?

Comment: The problem is `ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();` is shadowing your `private static pokeGrid world = new pokeGrid();` so you're operating and showing on the unmodified `ActorWorld`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico This has worked, thanks, maybe if it becomes open again you can post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static pokeGrid world = new pokeGrid();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();

    ...
}
```

The problem here is that the `world` variable of base type `ActorWorld` declared in `main` is shadowing your `pokeGrid` member variable `world`. The subsequent method calls on `world` are thus operating on a default world type, not your customized one.

To fix this, remove the `ActorWorld world = ...` declaration from `main`. The method calls will then be operating on your customized class.